# Trouble publishing a new azure web role from visual studio 10

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am trying to create a new instance of a web role via the "publish" setting in visual studio 10. However it seems to get stuck during publishing:

```
13:30:32 - Warning: There are package validation warnings.
13:30:32 - Preparing deployment for PHPService - 02/04/2013 13:30:11 with Subscription ID 'xxxxxxxxxx' using Service Management URL 'https://management.core.windows.net/'...
13:30:32 - Connecting...
13:30:38 - Uploading Certificates...
13:30:57 - Verifying storage account 'xxxxxxxxx'...
13:31:00 - Uploading Package...
13:31:57 - Updating...
13:33:07 - Instance 0 of role PHPWebRole is creating the virtual machine
13:33:08 - Created Deployment ID: xxxxxxxxxxxxx.
13:33:08 - Starting...
13:33:27 - Initializing...
13:33:27 - Instance 0 of role PHPWebRole is in an unknown state
13:34:01 - Instance 0 of role PHPWebRole is starting the virtual machine
13:34:39 - Instance 0 of role PHPWebRole is in an unknown state
13:35:14 - Instance 0 of role PHPWebRole is busy
```

It get stuck at busy, thus I am unable to use my web role.

Why is this happening, and how can I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you see when visiting the management portal? https://manage.windowsazure.com - It should provide details on the dashboard for PHPService. Check your usage as well and verify you have available cores on your subscription for deployment.

Comment: Do you have any custom code in the OnStart() Method under WebRole.cs (at root of the project)? If this Method fails the role can be stuck at "busy" (but should fail provisioning after a while). Also check the OSFamiliy, Size and Version in the ServiceConfiguration.